# Font Awesome icons innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, icons, font-awesome

I need to be able to put the icons into the innerHTML, but for some reason they aren't showing up.

The page is just showing little squares, which means that the code is invalid, so what is the correct code? I can't use the i tags because they have quotation marks: "" in the to show the class name and the true property for aria-hidden.

```js
document.getElementById("quizQ").innerHTML = "<h3>which icon is used for github?</h3><br>" + "<li>&#xf296;</li><br>" + "<li>&#xf113;</li><br>" + "<li>&#xf281</li>"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<header>
</header>
<main>
<div id="quizQ">

</div>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: You *can* and *should* use `<i>` tags; you just have to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the `fa` class:

```js
document.getElementById("quizQ")
  .innerHTML = "<h3>which icon is used for github?</h3><br>" +
               "<li class='fa'>&#xf296;</li><br>" + 
               "<li class='fa'>&#xf113;</li><br>" + 
               "<li class='fa'>&#xf281</li>"
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<header>
</header>
<main>
<div id="quizQ">

</div>
</main>
<footer>
</footer>
```

> That class handle the font that should be used to display the content. Without specifying the relevant font the browser will not display the relevant icon.

Comment: How to make  them clickable ?

Comment: You can try: `<li class='fa' onClick='handleClick'>&#xf296;</li>`

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the squares because your unicode entities don't exist in your default browser font.

&#xf296; is not a valid unicode character. It creates this:  See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f296/index.htm

&#xf113; is not a valid unicode character. It creates this: 

&#xf281; is not a valid unicode character. It creates this:  

Just so you know, there are two different types of quotation marks, and they can usually be enclosed within each other, so `string = "Say 'Hello' to my little friend."` is an acceptable string in most programming languages.

Unless you're trying to obfuscate the source code, which isn't part of your original question, try this:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("quizQ").innerHTML =
    "<h3>which icon is used for github?</h3><br>"
    + "<i class='fa fa-gitlab' aria-hidden='true'></i><br>"
    + "<i class='fa fa-rub' aria-hidden='true'></i><br>"
    + "<i class='fa fa-github' aria-hidden='true'></i>"

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is, because the font-awesome icons consist of 2 css classes: `fa` & `fa-iconname`. The symbols you're using probably corresponds with the second, but not the first.

I'd suggest adding `class="fa"` to your li's. If that doesn't work, consider the suggested setup: `<li><i class="fa fa-iconname" aria-hidden="true"></i></li>`